# How do I set File Version during runtime on a .sys file that my program creates

Tags: c++, windows, file, driver

I want my c++ program to create an empty .sys driver file, with "File Version" populated in the file details in Windows.  The file doesn't need anything else, just "File Version".  I also want to be able to change the file version or create a new file with a different file version.  I am using another program to read this file version.
How would I go about doing this?  Is there an easy way that does not involve the whole driver-making process?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://www.zachburlingame.com/2011/02/versioning-a-native-cc-binary-with-visual-studio/ - basically; the Win32 API has functions to do this, you just need to call them and provide the required information. Did you research *any* MSDN documentation *at all* before asking this?

Comment: I did.  I have been down a few paths that lead to file attribute editing, which is not what I need, and complete driver creation, which seems much too complicated for what I need.  
Your path seems to be setting the project exe's version number at compile time.  My program creates a bogus .sys file during runtime, and I would like the program to be able to set that .sys' file version after or during the .sys' creation. During runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I could not find a function that sets the file version, only gets.
I ended up creating a hello world driver and setting the file version of that with the method that Jesper linked (which is all preprocessor).  This compiles a .sys with a version number.

I analyzed the .sys file and found a couple of spots with version info.  One is in DWORD little-endian, this is what Windows grabs for file details.  The other is very close to it, stored as a string.  I am not sure which one the program I am interfacing with grabs so I am changing both.  Changing the string version does not change the file version in the file details. .sys files seem to have a sensitive file structure.  If you change something unrelated to the file version, Windows no longer parses the file correctly for the version.

[Here are the bits I changed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az6Ia.png) The string version is incremented by one because I was testing.